# What is the equivalent word for "compile" in an interpreted language?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, technology

In C, we say:

> GCC *compiles* `foo.c`.

For interpreters (such as [Lua](http://www.lua.org/about.html)), what is the equivalent verb?

> The Lua interpreter ***_*__*_*** `foo.lua`.

When I write instructions for users of my Lua script, I often say:

> Run the interpreter on `foo.lua`.

I think this can be said more succinctly:

> *Interpret* (or *Translate*) `foo.lua`.

but that sounds awkward for some reason (perhaps because I'm unsure of its correctness). I can't really say *compile* because users may confuse it with the usage of the [Lua compiler](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/luac.html) when I actually mean the [Lua interpreter](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/lua.html).

Comment: This should be posted to StackOverflow or Programmers.SE.

Comment: You’ve asked the wrong question.

Comment: Does an interpreter *compile* or *run* the machine code?!! I don't think so. An interpreter ***analyses and executes*** (execute and run may mean the same in programming but may mean different things in english) each LOC (line of code).

In any case, i don't think you will get accurate answers here. Try at programmers.SE.

Cheers!!

Comment: I disagree, because I think this is an interesting question in terms of English Usage.

Comment: I voted to close in light of the fact that OP has posted the same question on [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/151157/what-is-the-equivalent-word-for-compile-in-an-interpreted-language) and I think that will get him a better answer.  I am open to reopening if Programmers rejects his question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What about:

> The Lua interpreter executes foo.lua.

Or:

> The Lua interpreter runs foo.lua.

Seems pretty reasonable.

Comment: Yes - apart from being clumsy, precisely what OP wants to say *(the Lua interpreter **interprets** foo.lua)* is a pretty pointless utterance. Both yours are perfectly normal things to say.

Comment: Actually, the most generic and by that possibly the most fitting term could be 'to process'.

Answer (score 8):

I would probably write

> Lua interprets `foo.lua`

but if talking to someone not versed in my particular language, I might still use *compiles* as I would expect that to be broadly understood.

Comment: +1 for "Lua interprets foo.lua", but they're both fairly basic programming concepts, so if someone's not too familiar with *interprets* they're probably not familiar with *compiles* either. In that case, you could just say *runs*.

Answer (score 4):

I’m afraid that compiled does not mean what you think it means.

Almost all modern interpreted languages are compiled first. They just don’t generate native machine code to be executed by the hardware, but rather by some sort of pcode (pseudo-code) interpreter, or byte-code interpreter, or whatever makes sense for their representation.

Thus if you try to run a Perl program, the compiler will indicate syntax errors. If you don’t get any, then the interpreter is turned loose on the resulting compiled representation.

To a rough approximation, when you see “compile”, you should be thinking “parse”. And when you see “interpret”, you probably should be thinking “execute”, or perhaps even better, simply “run”.

And “code generation” is something else again.

Perl ***compiles and executes*** code.  Or it ***parses it and runs it***.  So do many other languages.

Comment: +1 for parse- interpreters *parse and execute*. I'm not sure that all interpreters compile to pcode though.  I've written many language parsers in lex/yacc (or flex/bison) that execute the instructions immediately in the yacc grammar and never go through the step of generating pcode with a separate pcode interpreter.

Comment: @Jim Right: the shell doesn’t compile, for example. But things like Java, Perl, Python, and Ruby all do.

Comment: See definitions of "compiled" and "interpreted" at, for example, http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/basics/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.zos.zappldev/zappldev_85.htm or http://en.kioskea.net/contents/langages/langages.php3. I think that pretty much by definition, if a language uses a compiler, it is not an "interpreted language". Java, Python, and others are often called "semi-interpreted" or "compiled/interpreted" (or as in my second reference there, "intermediary").

Answer (score 2):

The intermediate step between text and effect that is "compiling" doesn't exist in an interpreter; that's the distinction that defines the difference. You can trace the boundary with [Just-in-time compilation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) a.k.a. JIT.

Whether or not a language is "an interpreted" one started blurring decades ago and is slowly getting blurrier.  It looks to me like the distinction is inconsequential here, so I'd just say

```
run foo.lua
```

and

```
lua runs foo.lua
```

Answer (score 2):

As jthill points out, there is no action that corresponds to compiling in an interpreted language, so in one sense, your question is meaningless. It's like asking, "What's the word for 'claws' on a goldfish?"

But okay, the correct term for what you want is "interprets". And if you think it's awkward to say, "The Lua interpreter interprets the program", then just say, "Lua interprets the program." You'd have the same issue with a compiler. Sure, you could say, "The C compiler compiles the program", but normally we just say, "C compiles the program" or "We compile the C program" or some such. If it's necessary to specify "the Lua interpreter" for some reason, then I guess you could use an alternative word that could be synonymous with "interprets", like "executes" or "processes".

I'd add that while in everyday speech it's common to choose a synonym to avoid sounding repetitious, to give the sentence a certain rhythm, etc, you should be careful about this in technical writing. Many technical terms have precise meanings, and you can't just toss in a synonym because it "flows better". Like, my dictionary says that "drift" is a synonym for "float". But I think it would be a really bad idea to say, "Declare this variable as a drift" because you've already used the word "float" twice in the sentence!

Comment: I’m sorry to say this, and I do not mean to be rude, but this statement is nonsense: “ there is no action that corresponds to compiling in an interpreted language”.

Comment: @tchrist "Compiling" is translating from a human-readable version of a program to machine code. For example, you put a ".cc" in and get a ".exe" out. With interpreted languages, you never have an ".exe" file, there is no such translation process. So what would you consider the "corresponding process"?

Comment: Um no, [strictly speaking](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlglossary.html#C), that is incorrect. Compiling ***does not mean*** “generates machine code”. Rather, a compiler is “a program that munches up another program and spits out yet another file containing the program in a "more executable" form”. I assure you that if you take a compiler class in grad school — ***have you?*** — you will be made quite aware of the difference between compilation and code generation.

Comment: Yes, yes, my wording was imprecise. Today it is common to talk about "compiling to byte code". But that doesn't change my point: there's still no equivalent step in an interpreted language. (Unless you want to call a semi-interpreted language like Java an "interpreted language", but if you're going to nit-pick by description of what a compiler does, I'm sure you would never engage in any such imprecise terminology. :-)

Comment: And no, like Grace Hopper, I've never taken a compiler class. If you want to discuss credentials, I suppose I could mention my 32 years in the field, list the clients for whom I have done consulting work, titles of books and articles on IT that I have published, etc. But that would be boring. :-)

Comment: Check out my profile, sir.  I perfectly assure you that Perl compiles into an intermediate form, which in the normal course of things the Perl compiler then turns over to the Perl interpreter to execute.   I do know whereof I speak on this. My initial comment to you still stands: your statement that “there is no action that corresponds to compiling in an interpreted language” is sheer and uttermost nonsense. I strongly suggest you retract it.

Comment: (We're off on a tangent not relevant to this site, so I'll try to make this my last comment, let you have the last word if you like, and drop the subject.) I am well aware that there have been languages since at least Pascal that are compiled to byte-code, and then the byte-code is run by a virtual machine. These are not, by definition, "interpreted languages", because they have an intermediate compile step. They have been called "intermediary languages", "hybrid languages", and "compiled/interpreted languages". ...

Comment: ...  See, e.g. http://www.perl.com/doc/FMTEYEWTK/comp-vs-interp.html and http://ascherconsulting.com/what/is/the/difference/between/interpreted/and/compiled/languages/. Note, BTW, that none of this is really an attribute of the language, but of the environment. Java is normally thought of as an intermediary language, but people have written true compilers for it, i.e. that compile to an exe. If you want to use the language loosely and call Java and Python "interpreted languages", then yes, I guess you could say that an interpreted language could have a compile step. But then ...

Comment: ... if you use the language loosely, there's no point debating technicalities, because you've assumed them away.

Comment: Absolutely wrong: ***You’re*** the one using the language loosely.  I’ve written compilers.  I know the difference between compiling and code generating. You don’t.  End of story.

Answer (score 1):

The interpreter *interprets* the code, though I understand why you don't want to write that.  Other words you can use are *evaluate* or *execute*.  (I'm pretty sure that we used *evaluate* in Common LISP, but it's been a while.)

Answer (score 1):

If it is a true interpreter, that is, it reads the code as you have written it, and runs it directly form that, then it would be appropriate to say "the Lua Interpreter runs foo.lua" - because that is all it is doing, running a file of instructions. Exactly like the OS runs a .exe file as an output of a compilation.

If it is in fact pre-compiling it, or suchlike ( as might be suggested by the fact that there is a compiler too, although I am not at all familiar with the Lua language ), then either compiling or processing would be appropriate.

Using Interpret or Translate could be confusing, even though correct, because they are too specific - too detailed in terms of what is going on for the context. Especially in the former case, run is the usual word for taking a file and doing what it says. It actually doesn't matter how that process is done.

Comment: You're the only one to comment on _Interpret_ and _Translate_. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Programmers' common way of saying it can be

> Run the script

or

> Now run `foo.lua` and see what the result is